# php cache function not working on jquery .load()

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using a standard php cache script on page.php

```
   $cache = 'the_location/'.$id.'.html';
   $expire = time() -3600 ; 
   if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > $expire)
   {
    readfile($cache);
   } else {
   ob_start();
   // some stuff
   $pages = ob_get_contents();         
   ob_end_flush();         
           $fd = fopen("$cache", "w");
     if ($fd) {
           fwrite($fd,$pages);
        fclose($fd);
   }
    echo $pages ; }
```

On main_page.php I'm loading page.php like so:

```
   $('#div').load('page.php?id=' + id);
```

If I go straight to page.php?id=1234 the page is cached and file 1234.html appears in 'the_location'
Otherwise on main_page.php nothing happens ...

Help is much appreciated !

Edit : Everything works on main_page.php and page.php, page.php is correctly loaded into main_page.php but not cached, if I load page.php through browser it is cached.

Comment: `"$cache"` ? Is that better than using `(string)` or implicit conversion?

Comment: @alex: it is already a string to be clear ;-) He just doesn't know that variables can be specified as-is.

Comment: Just checked your CV zerkms... Nice! And no I didn't.

Comment: There's no apparent bug in the code you've shown (except for the indentation). The `.load()` looks unsuspicious. But can you try it without your caching logic around?

Comment: Everything worked/works before adding caching logic and after, just no page.php caching from main_page.php.

Comment: I might not have been very clear, I would like page.php to be served cached/ or be cached when loaded on to main_page

Comment: Try displaying the `/page.php?id=<main_page>` in your browser. Maybe there's an error coming up? (Now it sounds like that's where the issue might reside.)

Comment: if displayed through browser page is cached, but not through .load() function.

Comment: I believe that most browser cache pages loaded with jquery .load(), I need mine to be precache, or cache when expired

Comment: This may be a silly question, but do you have a div on your page with an id of div (`<div id="div"></div>`)? Because your code won't work without it.

Comment: @Bryan: Everything works on main_page and page.php, page.php is correctly loaded into main_page but not cached, if I load page.php through browser it is cached.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the page.php?id=1234 gets displayed, but the according *cache file* is never created? (but only when invoked via .load)

Comment: I think your javascript code is never called. If so maybe wrong id.

Comment: Could someone try and simulate this and give me their feedback on the matter? thx!

Answer (score 1):

I simulated this as basically as I could:

main_page.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="ctl00_Head1">

<script src="jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var id = <?=$_GET['id']?>;
  $(function(){
    $('#div').load('page.php?id=' + id);
  });
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="div">a</div>

</body>
</html>
```

page.php

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$cache = 'the_location/'.$id.'.html';
 $expire = time() -3600 ; 
 if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > $expire)
 {
  readfile($cache);
 } else {

 ob_start();
 echo 'This is a generated page';
  $pages = ob_get_contents();         
   ob_end_clean();

         $fd = fopen("$cache", "w");
   if ($fd) {
         fwrite($fd,$pages);
      fclose($fd);
    }            
  echo $pages; 
  }
```

This works for me.  Things I noted while working through the code.

1. make sure you are setting `id` to php's `$_GET['id']` in javascript in the main_page.php
2. make sure you are setting `$id = $_GET['id'];` on page.php
3. using `ob_end_flush();` along with echo `$pages` is repetitive (content gets flushed, then shows up twice when the page is regenerated), use `ob_end_clean()` or `$pages = ob_get_flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the request that is being sent using firebug? JQuery is probably appending a [cache-busting](http://www.crackajax.net/cachebust.php) GET variable to the URL hence busting your cache :D

Comment: Tried using Math.random(), in load function, but no luck!

Comment: Even added this to page.php `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");` Defeating the cache objective, just to see if file 1234.html would appear in directory.. no joy either.